# Estoy planteando asi este objeto pero no me da el resultado, me podrian decir xq?

Tags: javascript

Plantee el codigo de la siguiente manera, pero no me esta retornando lo esperado.
Alguien que me diga cual es el error?..

La función llamada recibe como argumento un objeto 'invitados', en el objeto tenemos objetos que representan los invitados
a una fiesta en donde todos tienen una propiedad "edad" .
debe retornar la cantidad de invitados que son menores de 18. ej:

```
// let invitados = {Luna: {edad: 25},Sebas: {edad: 7}
function cuantosMenores(invitados) {
  
  // Tu código aca:
    var contador = 0;
    for (var i in invitados) {
        if(i.edad < 18){
            contador ++
         }
    
    }
  return contador;
}
```

Comment: Utiliza `for (var i of Object.values(invitados))`

Comment: Perfecto! me lo soluciono, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable que llamas "i" es el nombre de la key en el objeto (Luna y Sebas). Debes hacer referencia al objeto anidado así "invitados[i]":

```js
function cuantosMenores(invitados) {
  // Tu código aca:
  var contador = 0;
  for (var i in invitados) {
    if (invitados[i].edad < 18) {
      contador++;
    }
  }
  return contador;
}
```